# Spring-Kafka Consumer KafkaListener cannot convert GenericMessage to Java Object

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-amqp, spring-kafka

I am posting some events of custom Java type 'InventoryEvent' through kafka-rest service running on Confluent-3.3.0 platform on Centos7 instance, using the below two steps:

> Command to POST JSON events into kafka-rest

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" --data '{"records" : [{"value" : {"id":1231, "eventType": "inventory.transaction", "qtyLevel" : 2223, "qtyReq" : 2345}}]}' "http://localhost:8082/topics/inventory"
```

> Subscribe the consumer instance to the topic

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"topics" : ["inventory"]}' http://localhost:8082/consumers/inventory_consumers/instances/consumer_1/subscription
```

Next I am consuming the events sent to the Kafka broker, via a Spring-Kafka application which should consume the JSON and convert it back to Java Type through the Consumer listener method annotated with @KafkaListener, like as below:

```
public class InventoryEventReceiver {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InventoryEventReceiver.class);

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics="inventory", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenWithHeaders(
            @Payload InventoryEvent event,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) Integer key,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset
            ) {

        System.out.println("EVENT HAS BEEN RECEIVED ");
        System.out.println(event.toString());


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String invEventInString = null;
        try {
            invEventInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event);
            System.out.println(invEventInString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

But I am getting the below error log in KafkaListenerContainer while trying to consume the messages via the above receiver code

The other listener method definitions that I tried but received the same error are :

> Listening with InventoryEvent object

```
@KafkaListener(topics="inventory", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenWithHeaders(
            InventoryEvent event )
```

> Listening with ConsumerRecord (taking cue from the error log)

```
@KafkaListener(topics="inventory", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?,?> record)
```

My Receiver Config below takes InventoryEvent as value placeholder. I changed that to String and added StringJsonMessageConverter through

```
containerFactory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
```

but it gave the same error.

Am I missing any basic Spring-Kafka configuration like MessageConverter or MessageListener OR is it that I have to implement a custom MessageConverter altogether to deserialize the JSON to Java type InventoryEvent ?

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class InventoryReceiverConfig {

    @Bean
    public static ConsumerFactory<String, InventoryEvent> consumerFactory() { 
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), 
                new JsonDeserializer<>(InventoryEvent.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public static ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, InventoryEvent> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, InventoryEvent> containerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        containerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        containerFactory.setConcurrency(3); 
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return containerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public static Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = new HashMap<>();
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"inventory_consumers");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class);
        return consumerProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public InventoryEventReceiver receiver() {
        return new InventoryEventReceiver();
    }

}
```

THE ERROR LOG:

```
2017-12-19 13:49:08.671 ERROR 16965 --- [fka-listener-23] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = inventory, partition = 0, offset = 48, CreateTime = 1513691348668, checksum = 537414172, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 77, key = null, value = {id=1231, eventType='inventory.transaction', qtyReq='2345', qtyLevel='2223'})

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.psl.kafka.spring.InventoryEventReceiver.listenWithHeaders(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,int,java.lang.String)]
Bean [com.psl.kafka.spring.InventoryEventReceiver@3ecc1b0b]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.psl.kafka.spring.InventoryEvent] to [java.lang.String] for GenericMessage [payload={id=1231, eventType='inventory.transaction', qtyReq='2345', qtyLevel='2223'}, headers={kafka_offset=48, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=inventory}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={id=1231, eventType='inventory.transaction', qtyReq='2345', qtyLevel='2223'}, headers={kafka_offset=48, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=inventory}]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:156) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:47) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:764) [spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:708) [spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2500(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:230) [spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:981) [spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.psl.kafka.spring.InventoryEvent] to [java.lang.String] for GenericMessage [payload={id=1231, eventType='inventory.transaction', qtyReq='2345', qtyLevel='2223'}, headers={kafka_offset=48, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=inventory}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={id=1231, eventType='inventory.transaction', qtyReq='2345', qtyLevel='2223'}, headers={kafka_offset=48, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=inventory}]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.psl.kafka.spring.InventoryEvent] to [java.lang.String] for GenericMessage [payload={id=1231, eventType='inventory.transaction', qtyReq='2345', qtyLevel='2223'}, headers={kafka_offset=48, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=inventory}]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:142) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:152) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 9 common frames omitted

2017-12-19 13:49:28.869  INFO 16965 --- [o-8080-exec-113] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-12-19 13:49:28.889  INFO 16965 --- [o-8080-exec-113] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 20 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your stack trace:

```
Method [public void com.psl.kafka.spring.InventoryEventReceiver.listenWithHeaders(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,int,java.lang.String)]
```

The method signature is like `listenWithHeaders(String, String, Integer, int, String)`

But you show us absolutely different one. Please, really be sure that you use the proper code at runtime.

If you have `JsonDeserializer`, you really don't need `StringJsonMessageConverter`, but the proper method must be used, indeed...

Comment: I have shown the listener method signature as shown in stack trace. In the InventoryEventReceiver class, I have annotated the listenWithHeaders with KafkaListener which is having arguments (String, String, Integer, int, String) as -                                        
             InventoryEvent event, (KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic, (KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) Integer key, (KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition, (KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset.

Comment: In addition, I have given two listener method signatures that I tried with same error. I am not using StringJsonMessageConverter, as I am doing JsonSerialize/JsonDeserialize for the value part in message

Comment: By the proper method, do you mean a custom MessageConverter for JsonDeserializer? If so, can you give a short example for that?

Comment: I checked in the link http://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka but no mention of any converter in the article. It just mentions about handling the custom message

Comment: Well, that’s not true: you show the method with the `InventiryEvent`, but at runtime the call is about a method with the `String` instead. I’m not sure how to convince you that there is something wrong with your app, but I won’t mind if you share the simple Spring Boot project to play from our side to reproduce the problem

Comment: Yes I can share the Spring Boot project. Pls provide an id to send

Comment: GitHub is a good public place to share. But bear in mind: that should be as simple as possible and concentrated on the problem only. That would to hard for us to try to understand your business logic. Thanks